# Submit Eclipse Project on Perforce

Tags: eclipse-plugin, perforce

I have a noob Perforce question. I got my perforce plug-in on Eclipse working(for both Java and C).

I have no problems "opening" my perforce stored projects on Eclipse.

Scenario 1:
Whenever I want to change code, I open the project on Eclipse and right-click on it and go to "team" and check out, make changes and then submit. Works fine. But even after that I see a tick mark(indicating check-out) on my perforce screen.

Scenario 2:
I just open perforce code as Eclipse project and make changes(If read only, it prompts and asks if i have to allow write and I say yes). I make changes and save. It doesnt ask for submit. Also if I now open the code on Perforce screen, I already see the new changes made.

Scenario 3:
Just on a Perforce screen, if I check a file out and don't make any changes, I obviously dont want to submit as there are no changes. In this case, how can i "disable" check-out so that my fellow programmers dont think i'm working on it??

Comment: S1: which screen still shows a checkout icon?

Comment: S2: When you see the new changes, does that mean they've already been submitted?  Where are you looking?

Comment: @p4-randall: S1: I see the icon on my perforce screen next to the code. s2: I see the changes done in eclipse(after saving) when I open the source code from the Perforce screen. My question is, are there default changelists generated and submitted when we work on eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Scenario3:

So here are 2 ways i consider a good usage of the plugin:

1. Use Revert Unchanged Files:
   Before you begin development of a feature, checkout the entire tree/branch that your changes will be concentrated around in future. You can do this by right-click the relevant package in package explorer. Once you want to submit, Project->Right-click->Team->Revert Unchanged Files. Now, you can submit your changelist.
   This approach stands very useful if you know you will be editing a lot of files or replacing files.
   Ofcourse, others can see that you have checked out the files.
2. Enable Auto checkout:
   Incase you are going to make few changes, you should enable autocheckout. This will checkout the file when you begin to make edits. Eclipse->Preferences->Team->Perforce->Enable support for workbench edit..
   [detailed explainations here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4eclipse/topics/preferences.html). Its a good idea to have this enabled always as it checks out on demand.
   However, this does not monitor the filesystem so and code/libs you replace outside of eclipse are not checked out.

Answer (score 1):

For Scenario 3, you can change a workspace option to prevent submitting unchanged files:

```
SubmitOptions:  reverttunchanged
```

If you have a file checked out (open for edit), others will be able to see that.  I guess I'm not clear on why you check a file out if you don't intend to modify it?

Comment: Err.. I check it out for modifying but then realise I dont want to make any changes... but is this "revertunchanged" an option when I right click my code on Perforce window???

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to setup this way and are also using the desktop client, I recommend the following steps in the desktop client:

1.) Open your desktop Perforce client

2.) Click “Connection” on the global menu

3.) Select “Edit Current Workspace…”

4.) Under the “Advanced” tab select “allwrite”

5.) Click Apply, then OK